# Position of width and height in jpeg header structure

Tags: c, parsing, header, jpeg

I am trying to parse jpeg header where in I need width and height of the frame. I went through many links but am still not clear on the structure. If anyone has concrete idea on the same, please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image (aka frame) dimensions are located in the SOF marker. You are looking for either:

```
FFC0, 
FFC1, or
FFC2
```

See slide 10 here for the structure

http://lad.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/multimidia/jpegmarker.pdf

The values are big endian, so you may have to reverse the bytes on your system.

Comment: Thanks but I want exactly from which offset I will get frame size. The parser I am writing needs the values.

Comment: You need to find one of the bit patterns above. They can be at any position. The offsets from that are shown in the PDF linked above.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't that straight forward. If you see "FF D8 FF E0" as the first few bytes, you use [JPEG File Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) which is as simple as casting the header to a struct. Looking at my own .jpg files though.. they all start with "FF D8 FF E1" which means they use [Exchangeable Image File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Technical), which seems to be a bit harder. You can find a library for doing that [here](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question. The problem is when I parse the height and width of the frame from the header structure given in the link( I had also referred the same link), I do not get any valid value.So, I am doubt if I am parsing the true values.

Comment: X density  2  Integer horizontal pixel density
Y density  2  Integer vertical pixel density . These values I am using for extracting width and height but values are not valid.

Comment: Do me a favor and run HxD on it, and copy and paste the start of the byte stream into chat.. like this and maybe I can be of more help:
FF D8 FF E1 55 8C 45 78 69 66 00 00 4D 4D 00 2A 00 00 00 08 00 09 01 0F 00 02 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 7A 01 10 00 02 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 84 01 1A 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 8C 01 1B 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 94 01 28 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 00 01 32 00 02 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 9C 02 13 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 87 69 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 B0 88 25 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 08 42 00 00 08 68 4D 6F 74 6F 72 6F 6C 61 00 00

Comment: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0101 0060
0060 0000 ffe1 0674 4578 6966 0000 4d4d
002a 0000 0008 0011 00fe 0004 0000 0001
0000 0000 0100 0004 0000 0001 0000 02b2
0101 0004 0000 0001 0000 02b2 0102 0003
0000 0004 0000 00da 0103 0003 0000 0001
0005 0000 0106 0003 0000 0001 0002 0000
0111 0004 0000 00ad 0000 00e2 0115 0003
0000 0001 0004 0000 0116 0004 0000 0001. Please find the HEX format of the file I am using

Comment: Good luck trying to find the frame dimensions using this method.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fixed format. If anyone is trying to do this you need to get used to stepping down the data a chunk at a time. Each chunk has a length that allows you to step onto the next chunk. Each chunk is identified bi ff then the chunk id. Once you know the chunk you can use a c struct to get data out of it, but as above remember all nonbyte numbers need to be converted to the correct ending format eg `0x2000` on the file would need `0x0020` on PC.